# How to convert Longitude/ Latitude and zoom level to Google coordinates in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, gps, coordinates

I want to write a function in c# which takes geo coordinates (for example, longitude = 30.23423432 latitude = 23.995454342 ) and a zoom level (for example, 12) and converts it to a google tile coordinates ( for example, x= 43234 y=26234 ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this post might help you out.

http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/browse_thread/thread/d2103ac29e95696f?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

An option is to utilize the UTM/MTM interface to Google. The link to it is http://leware.net/geo/utmgoogle.htm.